# Error: Parameter index out of range (39 > number of parameters, which is 38)

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

i am getting this error in dynamic java project.

**java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (39 > number of parameters, which is 38).**

I checked db column count is 38, "?" charachter count is 38, field count is 38, myStmt.set count is 38 but still i am getting this error. I am trying to write 3 tables in mysql, i suppose my method is wrong, can you help me, please?

```
try {
        myConn = getConnection();

        String sql = "insert into hodo (find_registry, title, name, surname, first_surname, start_date, structure_start_date, termination_date, mission_code, mission, " 
                + "profession_code, account_code, group_code, faculty_institute_hospital, department_unit, work_status, sgk_status, sgk_document_type, sgk_law, sgk_no, "
                + "detail_code, tc_no, father_name, mother_name, nationality, birth_place, birth_date, gender, blood_group, city, "
                + "county, district, marital_status, address, gsm_no, email, agi_information, lesson_load)"
                + " values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        myStmt = myConn.prepareStatement(sql);


        myStmt.setString(1, thePerson.getFind_registry());
        myStmt.setString(2, thePerson.getTitle());
        myStmt.setString(3, thePerson.getName());
        myStmt.setString(4, thePerson.getSurname());
        myStmt.setString(5, thePerson.getFirst_surname());
        myStmt.setDate(6, new java.sql.Date(thePerson.getStart_date().getTime()));
        myStmt.setDate(7, new java.sql.Date(thePerson.getStructure_start_date().getTime()));
        myStmt.setDate(8, new java.sql.Date(thePerson.getTermination_date().getTime()));
        myStmt.setString(9, thePerson.getMission_code());
        myStmt.setString(10, thePerson.getMission());
        myStmt.setString(11, thePerson.getProfession_code());
        myStmt.setString(12, thePerson.getAccount_code());
        myStmt.setString(13, thePerson.getGroup_code());
        myStmt.setString(14, thePerson.getFaculty_institute_hospital());
        myStmt.setString(15, thePerson.getDepartment_unit());
        myStmt.setString(16, thePerson.getWork_status());
        myStmt.setString(17, thePerson.getSgk_status());
        myStmt.setString(18, thePerson.getSgk_document_type());
        myStmt.setString(19, thePerson.getSgk_law());
        myStmt.setString(20, thePerson.getSgk_no());
        myStmt.setString(21, thePerson.getDetail_code());
        myStmt.setString(22, thePerson.getTc_no());
        myStmt.setString(23, thePerson.getFather_name());
        myStmt.setString(24, thePerson.getMother_name());
        myStmt.setString(25, thePerson.getNationality());
        myStmt.setString(26, thePerson.getBirth_place());
        myStmt.setDate(27, new java.sql.Date(thePerson.getBirth_date().getTime()));
        myStmt.setString(28, thePerson.getGender());
        myStmt.setString(29, thePerson.getBlood_group());
        myStmt.setString(30, thePerson.getCity());
        myStmt.setString(31, thePerson.getCounty());
        myStmt.setString(32, thePerson.getDistrict());
        myStmt.setString(33, thePerson.getMarital_status());
        myStmt.setString(34, thePerson.getAddress());
        myStmt.setString(35, thePerson.getGsm_no());
        myStmt.setString(36, thePerson.getEmail());
        myStmt.setString(37, thePerson.getAgi_information());
        myStmt.setString(38, thePerson.getLesson_load());

        myStmt.execute();

        myConn2 = getConnection();

        String sql2 = "insert into modo (name, surname, tc_no, person_type, nationality, birth_date, structure_start_date, termination_date, father_name, mother_name, "
                + "marital_status, blood_group, birth_place, city, county, district, registry_place, first_surname, registry_no, work_status, work_manner, title, "
                + " employment_situation, mission_code, profession_code, payroll_expense_center, wage_account_code, wage_type, mandatory_lesson_load, work_period_start_date, "
                + "start_date, agi, mandatory_bes_rate, health_insurance_status, document_type, bank_account_no, bank_no, branch_no, bounded_place, staff_status, phone, email, "
                + "address_type, post_code, county_name, address_detail, title_given_corporation, readership_field, readership_date, upsize_designation_date, "
                + "upsize_designation_status, mission_name, mission_place, is_noble, mission_status, ssk_registry_no, position, attending_insurance_branch, "
                + "item30_working_type, fraction_defective, closeness_degree, gender, is_agi)"
                + "values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        myStmt2 = myConn2.prepareStatement(sql);

        myStmt2.setString(1, thePerson.getName());
        myStmt2.setString(2, thePerson.getSurname());
        myStmt2.setString(3, thePerson.getTc_no());
        myStmt2.setString(4, thePerson.getPerson_type());
        myStmt2.setString(5, thePerson.getNationality());
        myStmt2.setDate(6, new java.sql.Date(thePerson.getBirth_date().getTime()));
        myStmt2.setDate(7, new java.sql.Date(thePerson.getStructure_start_date().getTime()));
        myStmt2.setDate(8, new java.sql.Date(thePerson.getTermination_date().getTime()));
        myStmt2.setString(9, thePerson.getFather_name());
        myStmt2.setString(10, thePerson.getMother_name());
        myStmt2.setString(11, thePerson.getMarital_status());
        myStmt2.setString(12, thePerson.getBlood_group());
        myStmt2.setString(13, thePerson.getBirth_place());
        myStmt2.setString(14, thePerson.getCity());
        myStmt2.setString(15, thePerson.getCounty());
        myStmt2.setString(16, thePerson.getDistrict());
        myStmt2.setString(17, thePerson.getRegistry_place());
        myStmt2.setString(18, thePerson.getFirst_surname());
        myStmt2.setString(19, thePerson.getRegistry_no());
        myStmt2.setString(20, thePerson.getWork_status());
        myStmt2.setString(21, thePerson.getWork_manner());
        myStmt2.setString(22, thePerson.getTitle());
        myStmt2.setString(23, thePerson.getEmployment_situation());
        myStmt2.setString(24, thePerson.getMission_code());
        myStmt2.setString(25, thePerson.getProfession_code());
        myStmt2.setString(26, thePerson.getPayroll_expense_center());
        myStmt2.setString(27, thePerson.getWage_account_code());
        myStmt2.setString(28, thePerson.getWage_type());
        myStmt2.setString(29, thePerson.getMandatory_lesson_load());
        myStmt2.setDate(30, new java.sql.Date(thePerson.getWork_period_start_date().getTime()));
        myStmt2.setDate(31, new java.sql.Date(thePerson.getStart_date().getTime()));
        myStmt2.setString(32, thePerson.getAgi());
        myStmt2.setString(33, thePerson.getMandatory_bes_rate());
        myStmt2.setString(34, thePerson.getHealth_insurance_status());
        myStmt2.setString(35, thePerson.getDocument_type());
        myStmt2.setString(36, thePerson.getBank_account_no());
        myStmt2.setString(37, thePerson.getBank_no());
        myStmt2.setString(38, thePerson.getBranch_no());
        myStmt2.setString(39, thePerson.getBounded_place());
        myStmt2.setString(40, thePerson.getStaff_status());
        myStmt2.setString(41, thePerson.getPhone());
        myStmt2.setString(42, thePerson.getEmail());
        myStmt2.setString(43, thePerson.getAddress_type());
        myStmt2.setString(44, thePerson.getPost_code());
        myStmt2.setString(45, thePerson.getCounty_name());
        myStmt2.setString(46, thePerson.getAddress_detail());
        myStmt2.setString(47, thePerson.getTitle_given_corporation());
        myStmt2.setString(48, thePerson.getReadership_field());
        myStmt2.setDate(49, new java.sql.Date(thePerson.getReadership_date().getTime()));
        myStmt2.setDate(50, new java.sql.Date(thePerson.getUpsize_designation_date().getTime()));
        myStmt2.setString(51, thePerson.getUpsize_designation_status());
        myStmt2.setString(52, thePerson.getMission_name());
        myStmt2.setString(53, thePerson.getMission_place());
        myStmt2.setString(54, thePerson.getIs_noble());
        myStmt2.setString(55, thePerson.getMission_status());
        myStmt2.setString(56, thePerson.getSsk_registry_no());
        myStmt2.setString(57, thePerson.getPosition());
        myStmt2.setString(58, thePerson.getAttending_insurance_branch());
        myStmt2.setString(59, thePerson.getItem30_working_type());
        myStmt2.setString(60, thePerson.getFraction_defective());
        myStmt2.setString(61, thePerson.getCloseness_degree());
        myStmt2.setString(62, thePerson.getGender());
        myStmt2.setString(63, thePerson.getIs_agi());

        myStmt2.execute();

        myConn3 = getConnection();

        String sql3 = "insert into kodo (name, surname, nationality, person_type, sgk_type, title, gender, marital_status, blood_group, trainer_type, registry_no, "
                + "corporation, sub_unit, department, working_type, continuation_type, start_date, end_date, active, mernis_no, country_code, city_code, county, district, birth_place, "
                + "birth_date, father_name, mother_name) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        myStmt3 = myConn3.prepareStatement(sql);

        myStmt3.setString(1, thePerson.getName());
        myStmt3.setString(2, thePerson.getSurname());
        myStmt3.setString(3, thePerson.getNationality());
        myStmt3.setString(4, thePerson.getPerson_type());
        myStmt3.setString(5, thePerson.getSgk_type());
        myStmt3.setString(6, thePerson.getTitle());
        myStmt3.setString(7, thePerson.getGender());
        myStmt3.setString(8, thePerson.getMarital_status());
        myStmt3.setString(9, thePerson.getBlood_group());
        myStmt3.setString(10, thePerson.getTrainer_type());
        myStmt3.setString(11, thePerson.getRegistry_no());
        myStmt3.setString(12, thePerson.getCorporation());
        myStmt3.setString(13, thePerson.getSub_unit());
        myStmt3.setString(14, thePerson.getDepartment());
        myStmt3.setString(15, thePerson.getWorking_type());
        myStmt3.setString(16, thePerson.getContinuation_type());
        myStmt3.setDate(17, new java.sql.Date(thePerson.getStart_date().getTime()));
        myStmt3.setDate(18, new java.sql.Date(thePerson.getEnd_date().getTime()));
        myStmt3.setString(19, thePerson.getActive());
        myStmt3.setString(20, thePerson.getMernis_no());
        myStmt3.setString(21, thePerson.getCountry_code());
        myStmt3.setString(22, thePerson.getCity_code());
        myStmt3.setString(23, thePerson.getCounty());
        myStmt3.setString(24, thePerson.getDistrict());
        myStmt3.setString(25, thePerson.getBirth_place());
        myStmt3.setDate(26, new java.sql.Date(thePerson.getBirth_date().getTime()));
        myStmt3.setString(27, thePerson.getFather_name());
        myStmt3.setString(28, thePerson.getMother_name());

        myStmt3.execute();

    }


    finally {
        close (myConn, myStmt);
        close (myConn2, myStmt2);
        close (myConn3, myStmt3);
    }
```

Comment: The error message suggests there's `setXXX(39, something)` somewhere. Do a clean build, so there's no chance of old code messing things up.

Comment: @foton7 are you sure that the issue is in **this** piece of code? For this exception I would expect something like `myStmt.setString(39,....)`

Comment: And with this table complexity you should be using an ORM; with it you would pass a single VO with all the properties.

Comment: Use a **local variable**. `try (PreparedStatement myStmt = ...) { ... }`. My guess is myStmt is a field, and it even might be the case the containing class is overridden, tried to "override" sql with a where, and added an additional parameter. _Wild guess._

Comment: @Kayaman there is no setXXX(39, something) in the code.

Comment: @foton7 yet that's what the error message says. Now I trust you if you say "I don't **see** any `setXXX(39, XXX)` in code. But that database driver sure sees it, because they don't usually throw exceptions for fun. So do a clean build to make sure you're not running any old code, and if the error continues, consult an excorcist.

Comment: @Kayaman i want to be sure before go to exorcist.
I cleaned tomcat and project but unfortunately it is same. Before you, think me how i am

Comment: The stacktrace should help you identify the line that triggers this exception.

Comment: now i edited my question. you can see my all try catch block. I am trying to write 3 tables. And my method is wrong i suppose.

Comment: Well the code doesn't seem wrong, although you could just use a single connection. Maybe comment out half of one block and do a binary search on which line it happens, if the stacktrace doesn't give you the exact line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code contains the line

```
      myStmt2 = myConn2.prepareStatement(sql);
```

I think you wanted to write

```
      myStmt2 = myConn2.prepareStatement(sql2);  // note: sql2 not sql
```

Otherwise you are preparing the first SQL statement again and setting parameters into it as if it were the second.

The same thing happens with

```
      myStmt3 = myConn3.prepareStatement(sql);
```

You want `sql3` instead of `sql` here.

Try extracting each SQL operation into separate methods.  For one thing, that would reduce the size of your method.  For another, you'd quickly find the error: the SQL string for the first statement would be out of scope in the second method.  Also, I'm not sure what you're writing your code in: any IDE worth its salt would warn you that your variables `sql2` and `sql3` are unused.